# Rendering Issues with Proxima Nova Web Font

Tags: website-design, fonts, web-fonts

We recently launched a new website (backtothebible.org) designed by an outside company. The site uses Proxima Nova. The font renders great except for a few sizes on PC's. The issue--which is an irregularity of thickness in some characters--is visible at 24px (used by our H3 style) & other sizes close to that. The rendering issue is most noticeable in the lowercase e, s & a.

The web designer has tried everything they know to try, so I'd be thrilled if you had any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about using a different font?

Comment: Here's an example of a page where the H3 styles look pretty bad. Looks fine on Macs though! http://www.backtothebible.org/printable-studies

Comment: Actually I'd disagree. It's a bit fuzzy on my Mac. It's appears to have uniform thickness, but it's not sharp unless I alter the page zoom (up or down).

Comment: Matt, we're hoping to find a solution rather than pull Proxima Nova from the site. Seems like many other sites are using it without issue...or it appears that way.

Comment: I would also suggest editing the question with what you have tried..  Not trying to be rude but that assists in better answers because I will ask you the simple questions of:  Have you tried replacing the font?  How are you calling the font?  Is this a hosted font? have you tested a hosted VS uploaded?  What are the browsers the PCs you're testing in?

Comment: Disabling `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;` fixes the "fuzzy" aspect in Chrome/Mac for me.